# svg matrix color filter doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to apply an SVG filter that turns the colors to a shade of red (207, 42, 39).
The matrix converts black (0, 0, 0, 1) to (207, 42, 39, 1).

I must be doing something wrong because the 2 colors should be the same but they are not

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <filter id="red">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="
             0.18823529411764706 0 0 0 0.8117647058823529
                0 0.8352941176470589 0 0 0.16470588235294117
                0 0 0.8470588235294118 0 0.15294117647058825
                0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>

    <g filter="url(#red)">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" />
    </g>

    <g>
        <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(207, 42, 39, 1)" />
    </g>
</svg>

<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <filter id="superred">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="
            1 0 0 0 1
            0 1 0 0 0
            0 0 1 0 0
            0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>

    <g filter="url(#superred)">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" />
    </g>

    <g>
        <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feColorMatrix filter runs in the [linearRGB colour space](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/3970/confusion-between-usages-of-linear-rgb-and-srgb) by default and not the sRGB colour space. I've changed the filter below to run in the sRGB colour space which would appear to be what you want.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <filter id="red">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values="
             0.18823529411764706 0 0 0 0.8117647058823529
                0 0.8352941176470589 0 0 0.16470588235294117
                0 0 0.8470588235294118 0 0.15294117647058825
                0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>

    <g filter="url(#red)">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" />
    </g>

    <g>
        <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(207, 42, 39, 1)" />
    </g>
</svg>

<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <filter id="superred">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="
            1 0 0 0 1
            0 1 0 0 0
            0 0 1 0 0
            0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>

    <g filter="url(#superred)">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" />
    </g>

    <g>
        <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="50" fill="rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```